# JQuery Add Multiple Re-sizable Divs on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

There are a few posts around on how to make a re-sizable div with JQuery. I'm using asp.net and used code from several posts to do this which is appended below. 
What I need to do now is have a button which when clicked I get another cloned draggable and re-sizable div, I also need to capture the x, y width and height of each div that is created. The code below captures these for the hard coded one and displays the values in a series of asp.net text boxes.

Cheers for any help and advice

Regards
CM

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs"   
Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Cloned Divs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-
ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
    #drag {
        width: 6em;
        height: 6em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 3px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }

    #Buttons {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        left: 50px;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#drag").draggable(
            {
                containment: $('body'),
                drag: function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var xPos = offset.left;
                    var yPos = offset.top;
                    var myHeight = $("#draggable").height();
                    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
                    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
                    $("#<%=txtX.ClientID%>").val(xPos);
                    $("#<%=txtY.ClientID%>").val(yPos);
                }
            }).resizable({
                resize: function (event, ui) {
                    var mywidth = $(event.target).width();
                    var myHeight = $(event.target).height();
                    $('#width').text('width: ' + mywidth);
                    $('#height').text('height: ' + myHeight);
                    $("#<%=txtWidth.ClientID%>").val(mywidth);
                    $("#<%=txtHeight.ClientID%>").val(myHeight);
                }

            });
    });

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {

            var structure = $('<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content"></div>');
            $('#body').append(structure);

        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="drag" class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul>
            <li id="posX"></li>
            <li id="posY"></li>
            <li id="width"></li>
            <li id="height"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Buttons">
        <asp:Label ID="lblX" runat="server" Text="X: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
 ID="txtX" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblY" runat="server" Text="Y: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox 
ID="txtY" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblWidth" runat="server" Text="Width: "></asp:Label><asp:TextBox
ID="txtWidth" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeight" runat="server" Text="Height: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Div" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have some serious css issues to deal with. I'm not entering this matter, but I'm going to answer you question about the div add.
The easiest approach would be turning your "$.draggable" event into a separate method, and apply the draggable property by a class, not an id. Then call it on every div add. Also, to append a element using JQuery use `$(document.body).append("")`.
Finally, you shouldn't use a asp:Button for this, but if you must, be sure to add a `OnClientClick="return false;"` property, otherwise it will submit your page.

Here's the javascript adjustments:

```
function ApplyDrag() {
    $(".draggable").draggable(
    {
        containment: $('body'),
        drag: function() {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            var myHeight = $("#draggable").height();
            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
            $("#<%=txtX.ClientID%>").val(xPos);
            $("#<%=txtY.ClientID%>").val(yPos);
        }
    }).resizable({
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            var mywidth = $(event.target).width();
            var myHeight = $(event.target).height();
            $('#width').text('width: ' + mywidth);
            $('#height').text('height: ' + myHeight);
            $("#<%=txtWidth.ClientID%>").val(mywidth);
            $("#<%=txtHeight.ClientID%>").val(myHeight);
        }

    });
}

$(function() {
    ApplyDrag();

    $('#<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>').click(function() {
        var structure = $('<div class="draggable ui-widget-content">BLABLA</div>');
        $(document.body).append(structure);
        ApplyDrag();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for the awesome and fast response.